# LDAP in CodeIgniter, Auth LDAP library

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap

I’m new in CodeIgniter development and new in LDAP. I have assignment to table users, for my web application, put in LDAP directory, not in MYSQL database table.

I begin with Auth LDAP library, but on beginning I have issues. When I try to login I got this message: ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Can’t contact LDAP server . How to make LDAP server? I found some tutorials about LDAP but not for LDAP in CodeIgniter.

Can somebody help me please? Or can give me link to some good tutorial about this topic?

Thank you!

Comment: As a rule of thumb when configuring ldap access, start with an unencrypted connection first, see if that works and only then move to ssl or tls encrypted connection. Your error is most likely related to some issue with certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and after changing the `use_tls settings` in config this problem has been solved, so change your `authldap config` like,

```
$config['use_tls'] = false;// by default, it is true
```